# Help getting the values of each set in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I could have sworn this was a thing but I can't find any math about it. Was hoping someone would help me figure out how to write it.

Say I have 2 cups with 4 balls. Every ball has to go into a cup, then I can write the sets as

```
Cup 1    Cup 2
-----    -----
0        4
1        3
2        2
3        1
4        0
```

This is all well and fine, but what if I have 3 cups and 4 balls, now I have

```
Cup 1    Cup 2    Cup 3
-----    -----    -----
0        0        4
0        1        3
0        2        2
0        3        1
0        4        0
1        0        3
1        1        2
1        2        1
1        3        0
2        0        2
2        1        1
2        2        0
3        0        1
3        1        0
4        0        0
```

The number of sets gets dramatically larger and I think in general, combinatorics is good at telling us how many sets there will be. Say I've ordered each combination above though, is there some $f(x, y)$ where x is the set number, and y is the index in the set such that I can pull out the values above?

For example $f(1, 3) = 4$, that is the first row, third value. Whereas $f(3,3) = 2$, which is the third set third value.

Also, can it be generalized to m cups with r balls in each cup?

I don't know if combinatorics is built to do this kind of calculation.

Comment: You’re trying to count the number of solutions of $x_1+x_2+ \ldots +x_m=r$ in non-negative integers.  This is a classic “stars-and-bars” problem and the answer is $\binom{r+m-1}{r}$.  If you want a formula that enumerates the solutions in lexicographic order, you can probably find it by induction using some kind of recursion formula.

Comment: Thank you, I haven't heard of the "stars-and-bars" problem, I'll look it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some terminology and a reference for your question.  You're wanting to run through, in lexicographic order, the $m$-part integer compositions of $r$ with 0 allowed as a part.  This is one of the eight equivalent combinatorial objects treated in section 7.2.1.3 "Generating all combinations" of Donald Knuth's *The Art of Computer Programming, Vol 4A*.

Comment: I've gone and bought myself a copy, thank you so much!